# Android getting started tutorial, Why use fragments?

Tags: android

Im following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) tutorial to get started with android.

In the tutorial they ask you to add the following code :

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                  container, false);
          return rootView;
    }
```

But this created class looks like it is never used, if i delete the code the code seems to work fine. Why do i need to add this code?
s sugested by two already where they say you need it in onCreate : the tutorial gives the following:

```
The complete onCreate() method for DisplayMessageActivity now looks like this:
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // Get the message from the intent
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

 // Create the text view
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setTextSize(40);
 textView.setText(message);

 // Set the text view as the activity layout
 setContentView(textView);
}
```

It isnt called in there anymore after following the tutorial, and before this is removed you cant compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

> But this created class looks like it is never used

Yes, it is, in the `onCreate()` method of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

You will notice `PlaceholderFragment` in the `add()` call inside the `if` block.

> if i delete the code the code seems to work fine

Then you have a different `onCreate()` method, or you have a `PlaceholderFragment` that you are getting from elsewhere.

Comment: later in the tutorial they tell you to delete that part in the oncreate function

Comment: @SvenB: And at that point, it is safe to delete `PlaceholderFragment`. I cannot speculate why they bothered with `PlaceholderFragment` in the first place, nor why they did not tell you to delete it as part of rewriting `onCreate()`. But, at the time when `PlaceholderFragment` is introduced, it is needed, based upon the initial implementation `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need this code because in the tutorial, the second activity have a fragment. So, the content of the activity is determined by the content of the fragment. You cant see it in this code:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

And the content of the fragment is determined by the content of fragment_display_message.xml. And that is what the code you post does (call fragment_display_message.xml):

```
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: later in the tutorial they tell you to delete that part in the oncreate function

Comment: Nop. The tutorial said you have to remove the onCreateOptionsMenu method. That's so different. That's the menu of  the app. In the tutorial you don't have to use it. I cite: "Remove the onCreateOptionsMenu() method.
You won't need it for this app."

Comment: but look at the code under : The complete onCreate() method for DisplayMessageActivity now looks like this:

Comment: That's because who make the tutorial decide to replace the view (fragment) for a TextView. That's why setContentView(PlaceHolderFragment) is replaced by setContentView(TextView). But if you want to have a custom view with many components, you have to add these to your PlaceHolderFragment and then pass it as an argument to setContentView.

Comment: It seems very useless if they ask you to add it, but you cant compile the code when using it.

Comment: If you can't compile the code before maybe is because you've not created the class (PlaceHolderFragment) inside your activity.

Comment: According to the tutorial you shouldnt be able at that part, its just useless code as  @CommonsWare said but i didnt expect that in an official tutorial.

Comment: That's because fragment_display_message.xml isn't created at that time. But think when your app have more components than just a TextView. In that case you have to add these views to your fragment_display_message.xml and then pass the Fragment as an argument to setContentView. That's why they explain that. Please accept my answer if it was useful to you.